# How can I create an option in the print PDF pop up menu with Automator?

Tags: messages, automator, pdf, printing

I tried to create a print plug-in for pdf pop-up menu, where I'd like to open the PDF in messages so I can send as a text or iMessage. After a few trials it did launch the messages app but it didn't show the pdf within it, nothing to send. Wanted to try the same plug in  with iBooks to see if it works and it did beautifully; saved the pdf to iBooks. I’m using the “open finder items” command. Is there something different I should do to make this work with messages app? My OS is BigSur 11.1.[image][image: PDF print pop up menu]

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing a screenshot of the entire Automator workflow, we can't possibly know what's wrong with the script. However: see my answer below for an easier way.

Comment: I added two screenshots. What you have suggested in your answer didn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Simply putting an Alias to the application in the `Library/PDF Services` folder *(either the User's Library folder or the root level /Library folder)* should be sufficient to send the PDF from the print menu's "Save As PDF" button to any application.

This should have the same effect as opening the document with the app, or dropping it on the app's icon. It may depend what the app does with incoming documents.